# Existence of periodic solution to ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I have added an ODE class a few weeks in and the lecture notes are not in English so I'm not very caught up on the material. Now I have come up on this problem I just can't find a way to solve. This is the problem:

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Consider the following initial value problem
\begin{equation}
    \ddot{x}(t) = -x^3(t) + x^4(t) \text{ for }t \geq 0 \tag{$\star$}
\end{equation}
with the initial condition $(x(0),  \dot{x}(0)) = (0, \epsilon)$. Find the suitable range of $\epsilon > 0$ so
that $(\star)$ admits a periodic solution.

My initial thoughts and observations are that $x(t)$ must be bounded by $1$ to be periodic as it would diverge otherwise. I've tried integrating both sides from $0$ to $t$ to get some information about the first derivative. But I can't quite seem to find the right path. I'm not looking for complete solution, I would just like to know what qualities of periodic solutions I ought to focus on and wether there are any techniques I should look into. Keep in mind this is from very early in the course so I probably shouldn't rely on any advanced theorems etc.. Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Hint. Multiplying by $\dot x$ and integrating $\frac 12\dot x^2+\frac 14x^4-\frac 15x^5 = \frac 12 \epsilon^2$

Comment: Possibly $\epsilon\lt \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}$.